# How to have a wrapper component in angular?

Tags: angular

I have feature component with form and few tables. And I would like to have a wrapper component which I can use in feature component wrapping in a wrapper component. To be detailed,

In wrapper component, my wrapper.component.html will have just a div with some classes.

```
     <div class="something"></div>
```

In feature component, feature.component.html would be :

```
     <my-wrapper>
        <div>with some data</div>
        <form></form>
     </my-wrapper>
```

But my content inside my-wrapper is not getting loaded. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a working stackblitz with a "wrapper" component.   Its a div with a class (and a red border style for demo purposes), and an example of how to use it inside AppComponent.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c6trj9

Wrapper component template

```html
<div class="some-wrapper" style="border: 1px solid red">
<ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Example usage of the new wrapper component (app-wrapper was the tag name given by default from angular cli, you can change it in the component)

```html
<h1>Wrapper component example</h1>
 <app-wrapper>
    <div>with some data</div>
    <form></form>
</app-wrapper>
```

Comment: That really works!! I guess Andrei was trying to tell the same thing but I couldn't catch it exactly. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is content projection. for the simplest case just use <ng-content> element like this

```
<div class="something">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comment: That's is not working though, I want wrapper to be used in feature component not other way round.

Comment: you will be able to use it anywhere. ng-content allows you to render everything you placed between wrapper opening a closing tag in the place of ng-content. if that is not what you were trying to achive then try to rephrase the question please

Comment: @Andrei Please add some more detail to answer. Your code explains not very well.

Comment: considering your suggestions, with ng-content also the content of the feature component is not showing which is wrapped inside <my-wrapper>. :(

Comment: Here's me, wasting hours to get @ViewChild to work, while the actual solution is simply this... Thanks.